# Need to upgrade from remarketing to dynamic remarketing

Tags: google-ads-api

I have some doubts on implementing dynamic remarketing for my site.
My site already uses remarketing. Now my client wants to implement dynamic remarketing.
I am a ColdFusion developer, I do not have much knowledge on adwards.
I know I need to add this snipet of code to my common page header for all product pages and  pass dynamic productid, pagetype value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var google_tag_params = {
  ecomm_prodid: '#productid#',
  ecomm_pagetype: '#pagetype#',
  ecomm_totalvalue: '#amount#'
 };
</script>
```

Do I need any more steps to do as a developer? My client already having a marketing team who manages all these adword things

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is basically what you need to do, except that `ecomm_totalvalue` should only go on the cart/basket & conversion pages - on product pages you should use `ecomm_pvalue`.   When passing in values for pvalue or totalvalue you should pass this as a normal javascript number and not a string (and should never have a currency symbol), e.g. `ecomm_totalvalue: 34.99` and not `ecomm_totalvalue: '$34.99'`

There are some detailed technical docs that talk through how to do this on the Google Developers site here - it doesn't have ColdFusion examples but hopefully it will help more (also make sure you check out the parameter reference section): https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/